# Data driven testing using csv\excel file in protractor

Tags: protractor

I want to add data to my protractor test from an excel\csv file. I can not find any simple\easy way to do that. my data is a list of first name and last name in excel which i need to create some user account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Excel file using node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860728/reading-excel-file-using-node-js)

Comment: Also a good way of posting question on SO is to tell what you googled,tried and where you are stuck

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [excel to json convertor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-as-json). So make sure you write code for `json` only as below.
So whether it is `excel` or `json` or input data will always be `json`.
Reach back to me for any query.

`test.json` file

`[
{
 "username": "user",
 "passwordField": "pass12345"
}
]`

`book1.xlsx` file

[image]

Suppose your `json` is stored under `D:/node_modules/test.json`
and `excel` is at `D:/node_modules/book1.xlsx`

```
import {protractor,element,browser,$,$$, By,by,wrapDriver,ExpectedConditions} from 'protractor';

var convertExcel = require('excel-as-json').processFile;
convertExcel('D:/node_modules/book1.xlsx', 'D:/node_modules/book1.json');

 describe ('Login Page Data Driven' , function() {
 browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;  

    beforeEach(function(){
     browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;
     browser.get('url');
     browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
     });
       it('To verify Login, using Data Driven Technique from Json file', function(){
        var testData = require('D:/node_modules/test.json'); 
        var a = element(by.id("username"));
        var b = element(by.id("password"));
        a.sendKeys(testData[1].username);
        b.sendKeys(testData[1].passwordField); 
        browser.sleep(1000);
        }); 

       it('To verify Login, using Data Driven Technique from Excel file', function(){
       var testData1 = require('D:/node_modules/book1.json');
       var a = element(by.id("username"));
       var b = element(by.id("password"));
       a.sendKeys(testData1[0].username);
       b.sendKeys(testData1[0].passwordField); 
       browser.sleep(1000);
       });
 });
```

Comment: excel-as-json, doesn't take the relative path of testdata workbook