# NPM 'excel' module returns empty array after parsing, in electron app

Tags: node.js, excel, npm, electron, node-modules

In my electron application excel module returns no errors, but always an empty array

```
const parseXlsx = require('excel');
parseXlsx(stream, function(err, data) {
    if(err) cb(err,null);

    cb(null,data);
});
```

`data` does not depend from `stream` param, whether it is path or stream.

In Node.js application this module works as expected.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this should not tagged as Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm install excel --save

var parseXlsx = require('excel');

parseXlsx('Spreadsheet.xlsx', function(err, data) { //need to pass path to excel-shhet or stream
  if(err) throw err;// throw error
  console.log(data);// data is an array of arrays
});
 Or
```

> use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)
>
> check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860728/reading-excel-file-using-node-js)

Comment: Please check your path given to the excel sheet is correct

Comment: than re-install your module and make sure data exist in .xlsx file

Comment: what is your file extension xls or xlsx ?

Comment: Xlsx, I am sure that the issue does not depend on my input

Comment: i have updated my answer check those links will help you!

Comment: Ok, will have to