# How to get user input in protractor tool

Tags: protractor

Actually I want to get user input from user whoever runs the script. I do not want to hardcode the testdata path in the script. for example when I run a script to test angularjs using protractor and javascript. User should be able  to give path of the testdata, so that I can use that variable inside the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by passing in a `params.testData` value from the command line.

```
protractor conf.js --params.testData=D:\path\to\testdata.xlsx
```

Then in your test you will reference it using the global `browser.params` object. You will also need to use `fs` to read the file and process the data. Honestly, it would probably be easier if you created a `.json` file for the test data instead of an `.xlsx` but it looks there are libraries out there to help you parse an xlsx document already if you have to stick with that. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28862951/2140747) answer for some examples.

This code will not work as is but the basic idea will be something like this:

```
before(() => {
  const testDataPath = browser.params.testData;

  fs.readFile(testDataPath, (err, data) => {
    if(err) { // fail? };

    const testData = data;

    // do some other stuff with test data ...
  });       
}
```

You are going to need to do some additional processing of the data from the `.xlsx` file to get it in the correct format but this should hopefully help get you on the right path.

Comment: Please, I want this to be implemented in the spec file. how can we do that.

Comment: I gave an example of how to use it in your spec file. `const testData = browser.params.testData;` Is this not what you mean? I'm not sure what you mean by "path of the test data".

Comment: Updated my answer with an example of using it in a spec file.

Comment: for example I am having an excel file with username and password in a path D:/testdata/testdata.xlsx. So other user who runs this script should be able to give the path in the console and the spec file should use this variable and run the scripts.

Comment: Ok, I'll update my answer with an example in a few minutes.