# How to read data from excel(XLSX) excel Protractor?

Tags: javascript, excel, protractor

I am Very much new to Protractor . So can any body please help me to get the date from xlsx file to the web apps. Below is the code which I wrote.

```
   var testData1 = require('path/book1.xlsx');
   var a = element(by.id("Name"));
   var b = element(by.id("Description"));
   a.sendKeys(testData1[0].Name);
   b.sendKeys(testData1[0].Description); 
   browser.sleep(3000);
```

I am Getting this error`

```
 Message:
   Failed: Invalid or unexpected token
 Stack:
   D:\Protractor\book1.xlsx:1
   (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { PK♥♦¶
```

this if xlsx file

[image]
                                                                   ^`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Excel file using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860728/reading-excel-file-using-node-js)

Comment: @Gunderson I have tried the above code and its not working for me Can you please help me out I am very much new to protractor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [node-xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xlsx) as project dependency by execute `npm install -S node-xlsx`

//excelAgent.js

```
 var xlsx = require('node-xlsx');

 exports.read = function(_file) {
    var xlsObject = xlsx.parse(_file);

    return xlsObject? xlsObject:[];
 }
```

// test.js

```
var excelAgent = require('./excelAgent.js');

var excelFile = '';
var data = excelAgent.read(excelFile)[0].data; // first sheet's data
var data = excelAgent.read(excelFile)[1].data; // second sheet's data
```

// project folder structure:

[image]

// folder `node_modues` structure:

[image]

Comment: thanks But I am Getting this **Failed: Cannot find module 'node-xlsx'** and on the `_file` I have given the file path am I right . I have Executed the  command `npm install -S node-xlsx`

Comment: After execute `npm install -S node-xlsx`, can you find folder: `node-xlsx` under folder: `node_modules`?   Did `test.js` and `excelAgent.js`has same parent folder as `node_modules`?

Comment: I am getting this error after i have made all the changes you told above  **Failed: xlsx is not defined**

Comment: Please get demonstrate project I prepared from https://github.com/yongcy/stackoverflow/tree/read-excel

Comment: Thanks Man. its working absolutely fine for me now.
Can we save the cell data like **1st column 1st row data**  in the other variable.