# How to read excel data in cucumber feature file using protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber, gherkin, cucumberjs

I can successfully run the test scenarios with example data mentioned in my feature file

```
Scenario Outline: Add two numebrs
  Given two numbers <number_1> and <number_2>
  When I add them
  Then Result is <number_3>

  Examples:
    |number_1|number_2|number_3|
    |2       |3       |5       |
    |1       |2       |3       |
```

But when i try to run the same feature file with example data stored in excel file it is not picking up any scenario and not throwing any errors also. My feature file looks like below.

```
Scenario Outline: Add two numebrs
  Given two numbers <number_1> and <number_2>
  When I add them
  Then Result is <number_3>

Examples: {'datafile': './testData/testdata123.xlsx'}
```

in testdata123.xlsx i have

please help on this.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this using protractor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read data from excel(XLSX) excel Protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382898/how-to-read-data-from-excelxlsx-excel-protractor)

Comment: I am trying to achieve this using cucumber with protractor, Its not related to my question

Comment: Read the question again. cucumber + protractor are written with javascript. Javascript is ran by node, which is js engine. xlsx can't be read by js directly, but you can use a node package to convert it to json and then manipulate in protractor

Comment: I am trying to achieve this using cucumber feature file with protractor, Its not related to my question

Comment: you'll be upset when find out that this answers your question, but you wasted your time looking for another one. I mean this is NOT the ONLY way solving the problem, but rather one of them. You just need to figure out how to import the plugin and use it within your script. But this is another question

Comment: unless you misstated the question. My understanding, you want to convert xlsx to json, import the json into your cucumber script written in typescript, and iterate thorugh every record. If this is the case then every item should be a separate question. And you need to provide the information, about what you've tried and what went wrong