# How to open a local excel sheet for editing on button click in electron?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am using electron for developing an application in which I need to open a local excel file on button click

```
<html>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function test() {
      var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
      Excel.Visible = true;
      Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/Lenovo/.electron/test.xlsx");
     }
     </script>

     <body>

         <form name="form1">
         <input type=button onClick="test();" value="Open File">
         <br><br>
         </form>

     </body>
</html>
```

The button click in this code does not work in electron.

Comment: Please add more details to you question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You should look at http://oss.sheetjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

Just add this code in html page and use electron message communication to execute this

```
<form name="form1">
  <input type=button onClick="test()" value="Open File">
</form>



 <script type="text/javascript">
      function test() {
        var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        Excel.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbooks.Open("teste.xlsx");
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: What happened when you did that ? Please elaborate with code or error.

Comment: You need to add proper path to the file in the code, if it won't find the mentioned file it will create new blank excel sheet. If it doesn't work, In next reply show us your full code that you are running.

Comment: The button click does not open any excel sheet in "electron".

Comment: @K.U. Code?  and stop deleting your comments.

Comment: <html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
      var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
      Excel.Visible = true;
      Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/Lenovo/.electron/test.xlsx");
    }
  </script>

  <body>

    <form name="form1">
      <input type=button onClick="test();" value="Open File">
      <br><br>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>

Comment: ActiveXObject() method is for only Internet Explorer only. so may be this stuck inside your electron as it is use chrome as browser.

Comment: So is there any solution available for this problem in electron

Comment: Follow this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28862951/6541218
this might be help.